# Help identifying a sci-fi book with short stories about portals

Tags: story-identification, books, teleportation

I'm trying to find a sci-fi book I read in the late 80's or early 90's. It contained several short stories, and each one was about the effect portal technology would have on human civilization.

In the first story, an unmanned probe lands on a planet (Mars?), it dumps out a portal, and an astronaut steps out of the portal.

Later in the book, there is a story about the day in the life of someone who commutes to their job on the other side of the country (world?) via portal.

I think (not super sure about this) all the stories were set along a common timeline, similar to Heinlein's A Past Through Tomorrow. Sadly, I can't remember if the stories were all written by the same author or different authors. I've been wondering about this book off and on for years - Thanks in advance for any help with the search!

Comment: This makes me think of the short story The Jaunt by Stephen King.

Comment: Another duplicate question, asked two years before the original. Yay.

Comment: @JohnO When there are duplicate questions, it is not required that the newer question be the one that is closed.

Comment: @Blackwood Still pretty skanky when the first person to vote-to-close is the same one hoping to drive traffic and upvotes to his own answer in the newer question. Also pretty skanky when you defend such things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is Harry Harrison's [*One Step From Earth*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Step_from_Earth) if I'm not mistaken.

The end story deals with people with 12 fingers. Can't say more without it being a spoiler.